# Alternative path not working

Tags: java, libgdx, path

I am using Android studio (libGDX), and I can't figure out why alternative paths doesn't work. I've tried it as it said in the book, but it doesn't do anything, it shows a black window and than the program exterminates.
If the .png file would be in the .../android/assets/ folder, it wouldn't work either.

Book: [Java Game Development with LibGDX 2nd edition](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484233238)

This is what the book wants me to do it:

```
public Spaceship(float x, float y, Stage s){

    super(x,y,s);
    loadTexture( "assets/spaceship.png" ); 
    setBoundaryPolygon(8);

    setAcceleration(200);
    setMaxSpeed(100);
    setDeceleration(10);
}
```

This is the shortest form that works for me:

```
public Spaceship(float x, float y, Stage stage) {

    super(x, y, stage);

    loadTexture("core/src/com/dusi/game/ch04/assets/spaceship.png");
    setBoundaryPolygon(8);

    setAcceleration(400);
    setMaxSpeed(200);
    setDeceleration(20);
}
```

This is what my path looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**For a Desktop Application**
If you are working on a desktop app it has to do with the Run/Debug Configuration:

[image: Example desktop configuration]

The important part is to set the "Working directory" to *YourGameName\android\assets*